# SMTPClient takes too long to send asp.net email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, mailmessage

I have here a bunch of code regarding SMTPClient Send mail:

```
  public void SendEmailToCustomer(ReservationDetails reservationDetails, string reason, string cardtype) {

    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email.Sender"], reservationDetails.Email);

    msg.Subject = this.Subject;
    msg.Body = this.Body.Replace("[InvoiceNumber]", reservationDetails.Invoice)
      .Replace("[GuestName]", reservationDetails.Name)
      .Replace("[GuestTelephone]", reservationDetails.Telephone)
      .Replace("[GuestEmail]", reservationDetails.Email)
      .Replace("[GuestAddress]", reservationDetails.Address)
      .Replace("[GuestCompany]", reservationDetails.CompanyName)
      .Replace("[GuestCompanyAddress]", reservationDetails.CompanyAddress)
      .Replace("[GuestCompanyNumber]", reservationDetails.CompanyNumber)
      .Replace("[OtherRemarks]", reservationDetails.Other)
      .Replace("[TransferDescription]", reservationDetails.TransferDescription)
      .Replace("[FlightArrivalDate]", reservationDetails.ArrivalDate)
      .Replace("[ETA]", reservationDetails.ETA)
      .Replace("[FlightArrival]", reservationDetails.FlightArrival)
      .Replace("[FlightDepartureDate]", reservationDetails.DepartureDate)
      .Replace("[ETD]", reservationDetails.ETD)
      .Replace("[FlightDeparture]", reservationDetails.FlightDeparture)
      .Replace("[NoOfNights]", reservationDetails.NoOfNights)
      .Replace("[CheckIn]", reservationDetails.CheckIn)
      .Replace("[CheckOut]", reservationDetails.CheckOut)
      .Replace("[RoomName]", reservationDetails.RoomName)
      .Replace("[Qty]", reservationDetails.Qty)
      .Replace("[RoomAmount]", String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(reservationDetails.RoomAmount)))
      .Replace("[RateRoom]", String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(reservationDetails.RateRoom)))
      .Replace("[NumExtra]", Convert.ToString(reservationDetails.NumExtra))
      .Replace("[ExtraAmount]", String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(reservationDetails.ExtraAmount)))
      .Replace("[RateExtra]", String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(reservationDetails.RateExtra)))
      .Replace("[RTTQty]", Convert.ToString(reservationDetails.RTTQty))
      .Replace("[RTT]", String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(reservationDetails.RTT)))
      .Replace("[RTTAmount]", String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(reservationDetails.RTTAmount)))
      .Replace("[TotalAmount]", String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDecimal(reservationDetails.TotalAmount)))
      .Replace("[ModePay]", reservationDetails.ModePayment)
      .Replace("[Reason]", "Reason: " + reason)
      .Replace("[CardType]", cardtype)
                 ;

    msg.CC.Add(this.AddressCC);
    msg.Bcc.Add(this.AddressBCC);
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    try {
      SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Smtp.Client"]);
      client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Smtp.Credentials.Username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Smtp.Credentials.Password"]);
      client.Send(msg);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //Do nothing
      //throw new Exception("Couldn't send email: <p>" + ex.Message);
    } finally {
      msg.Dispose();
    }

  }
```

It takes too long to send an email (approx. 5 seconds).
I also disposed MailMessage.

What could be the possible cause of the email delay. And how can I resolve the issue?

Many thanks!! :D

Comment: Have you run any diagnostics; checked any logs; sniffed any packets' checked any inboxes, etc?

Comment: @AndrewBarber it seems that when the SMTP Server used in other codes works well and smooth. Im not sure about the packets thingy, should let our info security dept do the thing.

Comment: How long would you expect it to take? Could it be another part of your code that's delaying this?

Comment: Further to your comment @user2962971 (and mine), I suspect if this works well in 'other codes' then the issue is with the context in which it's being ran. Please show us the rest of your code.

Comment: i first suspected that this may be due to the html format, but when i ran the program without the sending part, it redirected to another page (part of the program after sending email) fastly. But when i added again the sending part, it slowly redirects.

Comment: I just edited my post @DeeMac

Comment: Erg... I did some format editing, and I hope I didn't kill anything in the post...

Comment: what do you mean @AndrewBarber

Comment: I did an edit to improve some formatting to your post, and I'm worried I removed something in the stealth edit period.